# (Wordpress) Global variable to detect pagination?

Tags: wordpress

I am showing 6 posts on one page. On the 7th post, pagination occurs on so on.

**goal:**
*If* there is more than one page (page 1, 2, 3, etc..), JavaScript is to add a specific div element. If there are only 6 posts or less, no pagination occurs, no div element is added.

The number of posts to show:

```
$showposts = get_query_var('showposts');
```

The current post number I can keep track of:

```
    $post_count++;
```

*Problem is* I can keep track of posts 1-6 but how to tell if if it goes over to 7 and starts pagination? I thought there was a global variable that returns if pagination occurs, but I can't seem to find it.

(I know there is global to detect pagination via `<!--nextpage-->` but so far I can't find it's equivalent for index.php).

Answer (score 5):

*$paged* is a global var that is set to the page number WP is displaying.

Comment: this is a correct and direct answer to the question, consider marking this answer as accepted.

Comment: Where is `$paged` first defined?